# How do I limit same search results on my auto suggesting program?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `Pets` that has a column of `owner_name`. The user wants to put the owner's name and it will suggest the possible owner names kinda like if I put `Jo` on the search box, it suggests `John`,`Jonathan`,`Joshua`,`Jorge`. But the problem is, there are times when an owner has multiple columns under their name with different pets. Kinda like `John` owns a `cat`,`dog`,`bird`. My program does the search suggestion but the problem is that it repeats the names, so if I typed `Joh` it lists three `Johns` on the auto suggest. Out of curiosity I tried the LIMIT 1 but as expected, what it did was limited the entire results to 1 so if I put `Jo`, it just displays John.

Comment: use DISTINCT for no dublicates

Comment: Can you post the SQL you did so far?

Comment: God is good answered it, although if you still want to know, my query goes like this: "SELECT owner_name FROM pets WHERE owner_name LIKE :query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword. Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnname
FROM query
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!, I didn't know such a sql statement existed, I had the habit of only studying things I needed since the programming world is vast but after seeing this I think I'll try to study all possible statements as I would need full knowledge on statements if I want to manipulate a database.